# Why does apply with function parameter fail for println and not print?

Tags: scala

When I passed a callback function into the apply method like so, I got compilation errors.

```
Foo[Int](println) // Error: overloaded method ... cannot be applied to (Unit)Foo[Int](println)
Foo[Int](f = println) // Error: overloaded method ... (f: Unit)Foo[Int](f = println)
Foo[Int]((x:Int) => println(x)) // Works!
```

At first I thought this was due to missing argument list because it works for `print`

```
Foo[Int](print(_)) // works
Foo[Int](f = print(_)) // works
Foo[Int]((x:Int) => print(x)) // works
```

But adding this still fails for `println`

```
Foo[Int](println(_)) // Error:(6, 18) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>) => println(x$1)) Foo[Int](println(_)) 
Foo[Int](f = println(_)) // Error:(7, 22) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2: <error>) => println(x$2)) Foo[Int](f = println(_))
Foo[Int]((x:Int) => println(x)) // works
```

Why don't the two first ways of passing in the println function work?
Is it the overloading of `println()` and `println(x: Any)` that causes problems for the compiler?

Below is a full example with companion object and case class for Foo as well as some other reactive stream code

```
package test

import org.reactivestreams.{Subscriber, Subscription};

object test extends App {
  Foo[Int](println) // Error: cannot be applied to (Unit)Foo[Int](println)
  Foo[Int](f = println) // Error: (f: Unit)Foo[Int](f = println)
  Foo[Int]((x:Int) => println(x)) // Works!
}

object Foo {
  def apply[T](f: T => Unit): Foo[T] = new Foo(
    new Subscriber[T] {
      override def onSubscribe(s: Subscription): Unit = {}
      override def onNext(t: T): Unit = f(t)
      override def onError(t: Throwable): Unit = {}
      override def onComplete(): Unit = {}
    }
  )
}
case class Foo[T] (delegate: Subscriber[T]) extends Subscriber[T] {
  override def onSubscribe(s: Subscription): Unit = {}
  override def onNext(t: T): Unit = {}
  override def onComplete(): Unit = {}
  override def onError(t: Throwable): Unit = {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the overloading of `println()` and `println(x: Any)` that causes a problem. The compiler can't infer which of the 2 methods you are referring to.

You can replicate this easily:

```scala
def x(): Unit = ???
def x(a: String): Unit = ???
def y(a: String): Unit = ???

Foo[String](x(_)) // doesn't compile
Foo[String](y(_)) // compiles

Foo[String](x(_: String)) // compiles, force the compiler to use the second implementation
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the `Foo[String](x(_: String))` syntax